# Angularjs $http get loads null data

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I have created separate service and controller and injected them into the
htapp module

I want to get the message in the url to be displayed in the html page but instead i am getting null value from the js script and it is displaying null in html page

```js
angular.module('htapp', []).service('testService',testService).controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);

function TestCtrl(testService, $log) {

    self.getMessage = function() {
      testService.get()
        .then(function(message) {
          $log.info(message);
          self.message = message;
        })
    }
  }
  //serivce method

function testService($http, $log) {
  this.get = function() {
    return $http({
        url: 'test-routes.herokuapp.com/test/hello',
        method: 'get'
      })
      .then(function successCallback(res) {
        return res.data.message;
      }, function errorCallback(res) {
        return res.data;
      })
    $log.info(res);
  }
}
```

```html
<!--HTML CODE-->

    <div ng-app="htapp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">{{test.message}}
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are missing `var self = this` in your controller. Or is it omitted in this snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('htapp', []).service('testService',testService).controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);

    function TestCtrl(testService, $log) {
        var test = this;
        test.getMessage = function() {
          testService.get()
            .then(function(message) {
              $log.info(message);
              self.message = message;
            })
        }
      }
      //serivce method

    function testService($http, $log) {
      this.get = function() {
        return $http({
            url: 'test-routes.herokuapp.com/test/hello',
            method: 'get'
          })
          .then(function successCallback(res) {
            return res.data.message;
          }, function errorCallback(res) {
            return res.data;
          })
        $log.info(res);
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="htapp">
   <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">{{test.message}}
   </div>
</div>
```

read more info [here](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)